# how i can use inverse of haystack and needle postion with strpos php function

Tags: php, string

I want to use strpos for find exploded string in the imploded array.
i have a bad list :
for example :
exam
test
i imploded those with space and in final to be like a string exam test and i have a string like this :
my string : example string
i exploded thats and having like this array :
0=> example
1=> string
now i want use strpos in inverse state like that to check example string and return me this : exam
because exam used in example word. therefore i want checking example have exam or test or not.

we know in normal strpos using like this :

```
$mystring = 'example string';
$mybad = array('exam', 'test');
foreach($mybad as $mybad){
$pos = strpos($mystring, $mybad);
if ($pos === false) {
echo "not found";
} else {
echo "The string '$mybad' was found in the string '$mystring'";
echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
}
```

but i want doing like the above description i wrote this code but doesn't work true.

```
$mystring = 'example string';
$mystring = explode(" ", $mystring);
$mybad = array('exam', 'test');
$mybad = implode(" ", $mybad);
foreach($mystring as $mystring){
$pos = strpos($mybad, $mystring);
if ($pos === false) {
echo "not found";
} else {
echo "The string '$mybad' was found in the string '$mystring'";
echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
}
```

Please help me and tell what method should I use.

thanks all.

Comment: No idea what you are trying to ask here, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood what you wanted to say, but I tried to create some useful out of it. Maybe it's at least a basis to talk about.

```
$mystring = 'example string';
$mystring_array = explode(" ", $mystring);
$mybad_array = array('exam', 'test');
foreach($mystring_array as $mystring_element) {
    foreach($mybad_array as $mybad_element) {
        $pos = strpos($mystring_element, $mybad_element);
        if($pos === false) {
            echo "<br>The string '$mybad_element' was not found in the string '$mystring_element'";
        } else {
            echo "<br>The string '$mybad_element' was found in the string '$mystring_element'";
            echo " and exists at position $pos";
        }
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
The string 'exam' was found in the string 'example' and exists at position 0
The string 'test' was not found in the string 'example'
The string 'exam' was not found in the string 'string'
The string 'test' was not found in the string 'string'
```

Comment: I mean is not this way. I want exactly the opposite way. I want bad words as a haystack and my string as a needle I are checked. Namely with checking tell me that in the first example above is one example of the word are exam. like this example => exam ple

Comment: 'example' as a needle will not be found in a haystack 'exam test'. This is a totally wrong approach.